# Stop Sphinx Indexer From Auto Indexing

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I'm having a weird issue since I installed sphinx on my Ubuntu Server. I've noticed every so often, I'll see a sphinx config file sql query showing up in my Mysql processlist. After checking top, I see that it is in fact running. When I kill the query, the indexer seems to abort. How do I stop this? I'm using this config file, from a tutorial I found online:

```
source src1
{
type          = mysql

sql_host      = localhost
sql_user      = ***********
sql_pass      = ***********
sql_db        = ***********
sql_port      = 3306

sql_query     = \
SELECT id, group_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_added) AS date_added, title, 
content \
FROM documents

sql_attr_uint         = group_id
sql_attr_timestamp    = date_added
}
index test1
{
source            = src1
path              = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/test1
docinfo           = extern
}
searchd
{
listen            = 9306:mysql41
log               = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log
query_log         = /var/log/sphinxsearch/query.log
read_timeout      = 5
max_children      = 30
pid_file          = /var/run/sphinxsearch/searchd.pid
seamless_rotate   = 1
preopen_indexes   = 1
unlink_old        = 1
binlog_path       = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data
}
```

Comment: Something must be starting `indexer` - it doesnt spontainouslly start on its own. DId you perhaps install an crontab job to start it? Maybe you copy/pasted a command from the tutorial, without really thinking about it?

Comment: Have the same problem. The indexer starts automatically. Crontab is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the lines in the file /etc/cron.d/sphinxsearch

```
# Rebuild all indexes daily and notify searchd.
@daily      root . /etc/default/sphinxsearch && if [ "$START" = "yes" ] && [ -x /usr/bin/indexer ]; then /usr/bin/indexer --quiet --rotate --all; fi
```